# Use Custom Console Colors

Tags: c#, winapi, colors, console

To use different colors than provided via `ConsoleColor` I implemented code you can find on [p/invoke here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ConsoleFunctions.html).
This solution works fine, I can use every color/colorcode I want to visualize.
But `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX` only contains a few different colors. If I changed for example `ConsoleColor.White` to `Color.LimeGreen` and write text with this color, it'll be recolored, if I change `ConsoleColor.White` later to another Color. For example:

```
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("White text");  //text is white
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        ConsoleExtender.SetScreenColors(Color.Goldenrod, Color.Black);
        Console.WriteLine("Goldenrod text");  //both lines are goldenrod
        Console.ReadKey(true);
        ConsoleExtender.SetScreenColors(Color.LimeGreen, Color.Black);
        Console.WriteLine("LimeGreen text"); //all three lines are limegreen
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Is it possible to changes colors on runtime, without restyling text, which is already visible?

Comment: The console can only use 16 distinct colors.  You can modify the palette to remap one of those 16 color choices to a different color but if that logical color is already used for text in the console buffer then that's going to change the color of that existing text as well.  Use a different Console.ForegroundColor to avoid this.

Comment: If I understand correct, you mean I can use 16 different colors, but if I need more (maybe 32 or 64), there's no chance to use a color only for one letter, and then change the same color again without recoloring existing letters?